# Why typescript cannot detect this Svelte 3 store's correct content type telling me instead it is of any type?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

Using this code and [eslint-plugin-svelte3](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3):

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

    type Player = {
        name: string;
    };

    const playersStore = writable([] as Player[]);

    $: players = $playersStore;
</script>

{players}
```

I get this Typescript error:

`Unsafe assignment of an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`

on line:

```
$: players = $playersStore;
```

**Why?**

The error disappears if I use:

```
$: players = playersStore;
```

but I think this is not a solution: is an error, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the GitHub readme](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#installation-with-typescript):

> There are some limitations to these type-aware rules currently. Specifically, checks in the context of reactive assignments and store subscriptions will report false positives or false negatives, depending on the rule. In the case of reactive assignments, you can work around this by explicitly typing the reactive variable.

My suggestion would be to [turn off the offending rule](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1) for Svelte files until this limitation is adressed.